# How to disable context menu shadow in KDE 4?

Tags: kde, kde-4

I don't like context menu shadows in KDE 4. Is there any way to disable those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've looked all through the settings, and, sadly, couldn't find a way. Context menu shadows are not connected to window shadows...

But you may completely disable compositing/special effects (*Desktop Effects – KDE Control Module* → *Activation*) and that will get rid of all the shadows... and lots of other eye-candy.

Answer (score 1):

Run `kcmshell4 style` (also available somewhere from the menu in the System Settings application) and select a style to customise. *QtCurve* has many settings related to shadows.